# Interact with an android app through adb connection

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, adb

Is there a way to interact with an ap through adb connection?

I have a device that is inside a machine of mine that is far from my workstation. As i'm debugging  the app through an wireless adb, i'd like to press the app buttons,  insert the variables values through Android Studio.

Is that possible?

Comment: you can simulate touches using adb if that what you are looking for.

Comment: You can use vysor

Comment: @MatanKintzlinger Any tips?!?

Comment: @Chandrakanth i will look for..

Comment: @JonnyQuest for touches simulation: `adb shell input tap x y`. for keyboard press simulation: `adb shell input text <string>` or `adb shell input keyevent <event_code>`